# Extracting PDF rows to Rails db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, pdf

My source contains only 1,500 objects. At most it may grow to 2,000. I'm obtaining the objects via PDF and parsing with PDF Reader. They are parsed and returned by rows as String objects:

```
file = File.open("app/assets/images/file.pdf")
reader = PDF::Reader.new(file)
page = reader.pages[0]
rows = page.text.scan(/^.+/) #String Objects
rows.slice!(0..3)    #Removes Header Info
Sample object :

=> ["1", "3", "215", "06/02/83", "Law,", "Steve"]
```

Then I remove the "," appended to last name and split the String object thus creating a Array Object:

```
row = @rows[0].tr(',', '').split #Array Objects
=> ["1", "3", "215", "06/02/83", "Law", "Steve"]   #Array Object
```

I want to iterate through each row and insert into User table via console or form. What methods should I consider?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you getting any errors on inserting into the User table?

Comment: @iceman - I have no clue where to start. What methods are available for db insertion via iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have `mysql` with `users` table in it and `active_record` gem installed.

If you writing just plain ruby script first you need to require `active_record`(commonly used ORM in rails), establish connection to db and create `User` model to get access to the users table via `ActiveRecord`:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'active_record'  

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
  :adapter => 'mysql',  
  :host => 'localhost',  
  :database => 'your_db_name'  
)  

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

So now all you need to do is to iterate over the rows and call `User.create` method:

```
rows.slice!(0..3).each do |row|
  row.reverse! # reverse array so we can easily access its elements with ruby Array methods 
  first_name = row.first
  last_name = row.second.sub(/,/, '') # remove ',' symbol
  birth_date = row.third
  ...
  User.create(:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name, :birth_date => birth_date, ...) # I assumed you have first_name, last_name, ..., columns in your users table
end
```

Its all can be done in one file.

If you writing something like a rake task in your Rails environment you need to configure db connection in `config/database.yml` and create `User` model in `app/models` dir.